# Chrome not visible to 'flutter emulators' despite having set CHROME_EXECUTABLE env variable

Tags: flutter, android-studio, google-chrome, flutter-web

I would like to see Google Chrome listed in the available devices drop-down of Android Studio. I'm running Gnome on Arch Linux, and my default shell is ZSH.

I installed Flutter + Android Studio like so:

```sh
yay -S glu google-chrome
yay -S flutter # (with JDK 11)
sudo gpasswd -a $(whoami) flutterusers
sudo chown -R :flutterusers /opt/flutter
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/flutter/
echo 'export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="'$(which google-chrome-stable)'"' >> ~/.zshrc
flutter doctor
flutter upgrade
yay -S android-studio # (then I followed the Android Studio setup wizard, and also installed the Flutter and Dart plugins)
flutter doctor --android-licenses
flutter config --enable-web
```

I logged out of my Gnome session and logged back in, just to make sure every configuration change is now applied. I also opened and closed Google Chrome, just in case.

Opening an existing Flutter project with Android Studio only shows a device called "Pixel 3a API 30 x86", but no device named "Google Chrome" or similar.

Same when running the `flutter emulators` command from a shell, even though that same shell has `CHROME_EXECUTABLE` set to a valid Chrome executable:

```
1 available emulator:

Pixel_3a_API_30_x86 • Pixel_3a_API_30_x86 • Google • android

To run an emulator, run 'flutter emulators --launch <emulator id>'.
To create a new emulator, run 'flutter emulators --create [--name xyz]'.

You can find more information on managing emulators at the links below:
  https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds
  https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/avdmanager
```

The output of `flutter doctor -v` looks good to me, and even mentions Chrome among the available connected devices:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.0.6 at /opt/flutter
    • Framework revision 1d9032c7e1 (32 hours ago), 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
    • Engine revision 05e680e202
    • Dart version 2.12.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/ggiuffre/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • CHROME_EXECUTABLE = /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable

[✓] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.93

• No issues found!
```

In fact I can run a Flutter app on Chrome without any problem with `flutter run -d chrome` from the command-line. However, I would like to not have to type this manually (and have to manually reload and quit the app with `r` and `q` from the command line).

How can I see Google Chrome listed in `flutter emulators` and in the Android Studio drop-down, so that I can easily run Flutter apps by pressing the play button of Android Studio?

### Update

It makes sense that Chrome isn't listed when calling `flutter emulators`, as Chrome is not an Android emulator. In fact Chrome is listed when calling `flutter devices`. Given this, my question would then become: how can I get Android Studio to show both emulators *and* any other device (Chrome, in particular) under the drop-down that I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

`chrome` device doesn't appear in Android Studio because you don't have the flutter plugin installed:

```
[✓] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter  <============
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart     <============
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
```

By default additional plugins are installed in the folder **~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio**. There may be something wrong with permissions for this folder.

Comment: Thanks. `.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/` is owned by my user. I see that Flutter doctor says Android Studio is installed at `/opt/android-studio` which was owned by root, so I gave my user read/write permission to this directory and also set up two soft links `Dart` and `flutter-intellij` from `.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/` to `/opt/android-studio/plugins/`. Unfortunately Flutter doctor still complains about these two plugins not being installed, and Android Studio still does not show the Chrome device in the drop-down.

Comment: @Giorgio btw, are you sure that the project is opened as a `Flutter project` but not as `Android project`?

Comment: In the "Project" sidebar I can see the Flutter logo next to the name of my project, so I think Android Studio correctly recognized my project as a Flutter one.

Comment: Have you same problems with projects created from android studio start menu? (i.e. create new flutter project)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I see the same problem even after creating a test project with "new Flutter project".

Comment: By the way: on Ubuntu I can correctly see Chrome listed among the devices drop-down of Android Studio. So the issue that I see on Arch Linux might have something to do with some wrong assumption that Android Studio is making about paths to dependencies in the filesystem.

Comment: it's worth trying to start Android Studio from command line - there may be some error in the console.

Comment: Interesting! Now I can see the Chrome device from the drop-down, after starting from the command line... thanks a lot :) perhaps setting some env variables from my .zshrc wasn't enough for Android Studio to see them.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify.

Linux works with environments and if you set up the variable CHROME_EXECUTABLE in your shell will work if you open your IDE from the shell but if you want to fix it permanently you must modify the IDE dart.env like this

`"dart.env": { "CHROME_EXECUTABLE": "/path of your chrome or chromium browser" }`

> That env is for VScode but i guess you can do the same for android studio.